# expected , but found = in warning in netbeans for JS function with default parameter

Tags: javascript

```
function my_check_request(comp,load='')
{
    if(load==''){
        var btn = jQuery(comp).button('loading');
        //i will do something here
    }
    else{
        jQuery(comp).css("display", "inline");
        //i will do something here
    }
```

Getting the warning in Netbeans - expected , but found = 
Any better way for this?

Comment: Function default parameters is ES6+, try changing the JsLint to ES6.

Comment: If you can't use ES6, then maybe change `load=''` to `load` in the function declaration and add the following line: `load = (typeof load !== 'undefined') ?  load : '';` within the function body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function my_check_request(comp, load)
{
    load = load || '';
    if (load == '') {
        var btn = jQuery(comp).button('loading');
        //i will do something here
    } else {
        jQuery(comp).css("display", "inline");
        //i will do something here
    }
}
```

Changing the function like this resolved the issue